# Azure devops merge pull request from CLI

Tags: azure, azure-devops, azure-cli

I am trying to merge a pull request from an azure cli, but it does not work, here is the steps how I try:

```
        az repos pr update --id ${PR_ID} \
                           --bypass-policy true \
                           --bypass-policy-reason renovate \
                           --delete-source-branch true \
                           --squash true \
                           --org ${ORG}
```

The PR is from a feature branch to master, master has policies but the user which executes the az command has right to bypass policies and merge the PR.

I am getting back a JSON object as a response, no error message, and one of the properties even says that it is succeeded.

```
  "mergeStatus": "succeeded",
```

If I look at the azure portal it is still in active status.
What am I doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you should add the new status: completed

```
[--status {abandoned, active, completed}]
```

[az repos pr update](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/cli/azure/repos/pr?view=azure-cli-latest#az-repos-pr-update)

> --status
> Set the new state of pull request.

**Update**:

It works with `Bypass policies when completing pull requests` permissions.

The command:

```
az repos pr update --id {id} --status completed --bypass-policy true --org {org}
```

Result:

[image]

Permissions:

[image]

Comment: I have tried that, and it does not work, since it tries to check for the policies, for example I have a policy that work item must be linked, and when I set the status to completed using the cli I get the following error message: `The pull request must be linked to a work item before it can be completed.`

Comment: @Sunflame in this case `--bypass-policy true` does not work.... I`ll try to reproduce it..

Comment: @Sunflame I`ve tested.... it works. Check my updates